# Change workbench status from draft or needs review to publish programatically in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, workbench

I want to update a node status from draft or needs review to publish programatically in Drupal 8. Can anyone suggest which is the function used by WBM module to update the node status.

Thanks

Comment: This might work.
https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation/issues/2804865#comment-11813026